# Radius of convergence of a power series when its sequence of coefficients converges.

Tags: complex-analysis

Let {$a_n$} be a sequence of complex numbers with {$a_n$} converging to some "l" in $\mathbb C$. Then what's the minimum radius of convergence of the power series $\sum a_nz^n$?

I have proved the result that if $a_n$ converges to zero then the radius of convergence is at least one. If l$\ne 0$ then how to find the minimum radius of convergence?

Comment: If $\ell \neq 0$ then the radius of convergence is exactly $1$; use the ratio test.

Comment: Thank you very much. I got the point.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If $l\neq 0$, the radius of convergence ($\rho$) is exactly $1$. This follows from the Ratio test:

$$\rho^{-1}=\lim_{n\to \infty}\frac{a_{n+1}}{a_n}=\frac{l}{l}=1$$

If $l=0$, the only information we have is that $\rho\ge 1$.
Indeed, the series $$f_k(z)=\sum_\mathbb{N} \left(\frac zk\right)^n$$
has radius $\rho=k$ for every $k\ge 1$. Obviously, $\lim_{n\to \infty}a_n=\lim_{n\to \infty}k^{-n}=0$.